# Convergence of the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I tried using the logarithmic method. But I couldn't work with it as I am not sure we can apply L'Hospital to the indeterminate form -infinity/infinity.
Please help me prove the convergence.

Comment: do you mean $$a_n=\left(\sin(1/n)\right)^{1/n}$$

Comment: it is the same for $$n>0$$

Comment: No i meant (1/n)^(sin(1/n))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $x\sin(1) \leq \sin(x) \leq x$ by concavity, hence
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\sin(1/n)}} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{1/n}=1 $$
holds by squeezing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left(\sin \frac1n \right)^{1/n}=e^{\large \frac1n\ln \left(\sin \frac1n \right)}\sim e^{\Large-\frac{\ln n}n}.
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the final approximation?

Answer (score 0):

The result would follow if you are able to evaluate 
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sin x}.$$

Taking a logarithm is a good start, since 
\begin{align}
\log (x^{\sin x}) = \sin x \log x = \frac{\log x}{1/\sin x},
\end{align}
which is of type $\infty/\infty$. Thus L'Hospital rule applies:
\begin{align*} \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log x}{1/\sin x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1/x}{-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\cos x} 
=  -\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x\cos x} = 0.
\end{align*}
In the last step we used the relation $\sin x \sim x$ as $x \to 0^+$. 
Thus the answer to the original limit is $e^0 = 1$.

Comment: I guess the form we obtain from sinx* logx is -(infinity)/(infinity).Can we still apply L'Hospitals?

Comment: Yes, we can apply.

Answer (score -1):

use that $$|\sin(1/n)|\le 1$$ is hold